# Google Maps Panorama View in JqueryUI Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, jquery-ui, maps

I've got a strange thing happening with Google Panorama's. I am using JQueryUI Tabs to display multiple tabs of information which are updated by Ajax calls. If the tab with the panorama is open when I update the panorama, then everything works the way I expect it to. If another tab is open, then when I open the panorama tab, the view is grey and never shows the view.

My javascript is basically thus:

```
var geo_position = null || new google.maps.LatLng(data[0].Latitude, data[0].Longitude);
var service = null || new google.maps.StreetViewService();

service.getPanoramaByLocation(geo_position, 50, function(result, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
        $('#tabs').tabs("option", "active", 4);
        function svcheck() {
            var panoramaOptions = {
                position: geo_position,
                visible: true,
            };
            var panorama = null || new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('tabs-4'), panoramaOptions);
            $('#tabs-4').show(); 
            $('#svtab').show();
            panorama.setVisible(true);
            google.maps.event.trigger(panorama, 'resize');
        }
        svcheck();
    } else {
        $('#tabs').tabs("option", 0);
        $('#svtab').hide();
        $('#tabs-4').hide();
    }
});
```

This used to work with previous versions of Jquery/JQueryUI, but does not seem to be compatible with the current versions.